# How do I insert Follow Button plugin code to my Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I got this "Your Follow Button plugin code:" from my Facebook Developers page, but do not know how to place it in my Facebook Page. 
The pop up window gave me this:

Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening  tag.

And than bellow: 
Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

I am not savvy at all about this. I tried to place this code in my question, but got "Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:" Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Can you show the code for the page into which you're trying to insert it?  The SDK documentation should also specify how you include the SDK JavaScript reference.  Basically you need to reference Facebook's JavaScript file from your code (like you would any other JavaScript file, potentially) and then include the sample plugin somewhere in that code (which is pretty much copy/paste).

Answer (score 0):

you can't put the "follow button" directly onto your facebook page (aka timeline).

the social plugins can only be used in combination with your own website. copy/paste the correspsonding JS SDK code to your website and everything's working as expected!